# Angular 4 - include html file like SASS _partial

Tags: angular

I have my Angular 4 component files structure like following hierarchy -

```
-----add-form
-------_textfield.html
-------_teaxarea.html
-------add-form.component.ts
-------add-form.component.html
-------add-form.directives.ts
```

I have been trying to include `_textfield.html` or `_textarea.html` files within `add-form.component.html` like _partials of `SASS` or `include()` in PHP.

I tried with `ng-iinclude` with following code -

`<div ng-include="'_textfield.html'"></div>`

But it finally output itself. What is the best way to include these files?

Answer (score 0):

Angular works only with component. There is nothing like partial or include.

The only way to follow your hierarchy is to define one component for your `textfield.html` and one component for your `textarea.html`.

Then, you can use this components in your `add-form.component`

Comment: I tried at same way but couldn't make it happen - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45998572/angular-4-component-selector-not-working-in-custom-directive